# Independent of chat-integrated slide-casting app for Linux & Windows

Tags: networking, collaboration, slideshow, chromecast

I'd like to slide-cast a slide set of mine to some people, with whom I'm going to have a Skype conversation. Now, I'm using the 64-bit Skype for Linux beta, which doesn't have screen-casting; otherwise I would just screen-cast my slides, which is not the best solution but it would do the job.

Since that can't happen - what can I use to have people see the slide I want to on their monitor? I don't mind having them install something as well as me installing it; and it doesn't have to relate to Skype in any way.

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Runs on Windows and Linux
- Either screen-casts or casts a sequence of slides
- Speaker decides when slide transition happens
- Not very difficult to set up from the client side

Nice-to-have:

- Libre
- Lightweight
- Does something reasonable about speaker/audience monitor resolution differences